# Will a "String" table save space within my Access database?

Tags: ms-access

I'm designing an Access database which, coupled with a C# class library, will allow me to store and retrieve objects with arbitrary data types. The database will behave something like an EAV (Entity/Attribute/Value) store, where the record for each value will reference the entity name, attribute name, and data type (as well as the actual data stored as a serialized JSON (Javascript Object Notation) string.

Due to the nature of the database, I'll be using the same strings over and over again. For example, many records will have the string "System.Double" stored within the data type field. I'm therefore thinking of saving space by recording these strings in a table with an auto-incrementing integer primary key, which will be used instead of using the strings directly. So, for example, instead of having...

```
CREATE TABLE [Value] (
    ...
    [DataTypeName] VARCHAR NOT NULL,
    ...);
```

...I'd have...

```
CREATE TABLE [Name] (
    [NameID]    AUTOINCREMENT PRIMARY KEY,
    [NameValue] VARCHAR NOT NULL UNIQUE);

CREATE TABLE [Value] (
    ...
    [DataTypeNameID] INTEGER NOT NULL REFERENCES [Name],
    ...);
```

Would this be a good approach, or do Access databases have string compression built in for repetitively-used strings?

Comment: I'd argue that the "supported data types" are part of the code, not part of the user data. Thus, I'd suggest a third approach: In your code, define an Enum containing all your supported data types (i.e., the ones where your library knows how to stringify/unstringify them) and just store the enum value in the database.

Comment: @Heinzi the thing is, the supported data types can and will change as time goes on, which has led me to this method of storing the data.  Using an enum value will just get messy, as there will be potentially hundreds of different data types that are stored.

Comment: I see, makes sense. I do believe that your method of "caching" data types will save space (i.e. that Access does not have built-in string compression), but that's just a gut feeling, so I'm looking forward to an answer to your question. In any case, keep the "premature optimization is the root of all evil" saying in mind - is the difference large enough to matter in practice (and worth the effort and additional complexity)?

Comment: It depends on the namespaces that I'll be delving into, but a typical example could easily be over 100 characters in length used 100 or more times.  I've got other things as well as data type names, such as the names of individuals who sign off the data as checked/approved (there's a large element of quality assurance in the application, as it's being used for design automation).

Comment: Well, 100 data types * 100 characters (bytes) * 1000 uses each = 10 MB (+ some overhead), which is really not a lot.

Comment: "thinking of saving space" - Why? Do you fear running out of space? You would probably save much more space using `NameValue VARCHAR WITH COMPRESSION NOT NULL UNIQUE` assuming you don't actually require unicode.

Comment: Something else to keep in mind is that using tables to store commonly used values is generally a good practice regardless of space concerns.

Comment: @Heinzi: "Access does not have built-in string compression" - ironically the engine has had [compressible text data types](https://support.microsoft.com/en-us/kb/275561) since Jet 4.0 circa 2000.

Comment: @Rominus: just as Heinzi warns against premature optimization, I would be wary of your "is generally a good practice". You may be on to something but what specifically makes it good? Can you point to any design principles such as the principle of full normalization? Thanks.

Comment: @onedaywhen for example, it avoids dirty data due to misspellings of the same value, e.g. 'System.Double' and 'System-Double' if any manual data entry is involved; it enhances use of Access form elements like combo-boxes; it provides an index of what the valid values are.